# How safe is upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Being new to Ubuntu I try to avoid any install without looking for problems others have experienced. The upgrade to 12.04 seems to have had quite a few users experience problems.  Do these generally get resolved or are they sometimes bugs? Is there an approach that can be used to determine the impact on particular applications, or a list of known problem apps?

Update: Desktop, new with on board graphics. I guess I am just trying to get a handle on how smoothly upgrades are in general with Ubuntu. I am on 11 and shortly after got advised of the upgrade to 12 being available.

I do not think I have any special apps yet, but did install kubuntu too. Although switched back to Ubuntu most of the time. But seeing lots of the problems relate to basics like ethernet connections got a little nervous as I have no idea of the size of userbase and whether the experienced problems are a rarity or common issues. Do such issues feed back to devs and result in a maintenance release if a bug is uncovered for example.

Comment: What are you upgrading from? Is this a physical machine or a VM/VPS? If physical, desktop or laptop -- wireless card and graphics card models?

Comment: You could edit your question to include the apps you use or intend to use for people to provide specific feedback. Incidentally, you should keep in mind that it's mostly people who have problems who post, those without complaints don't. Overall, I feel your question, while legitimate, is too broad in scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04; uptil now things are working pretty good for me. So, would not be an issue at for you too.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, as long as you are upgrading from 11.X you shouldn't experience any issues. I upgraded from 11.10 and had no issues initially, but after a few reboots I ran into a weird DNS issue. I don't know the exact cause to this date. But I suspect it had something to do with the resolvconf configuration. This was a known bug which has been addressed and is no longer an issue.

I would go for the upgrade to 12.04 LTS, but as always, make sure you have a backup. If your disk isn't too large you can use [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page). It is extremely easy to use, supports compression, and will only backup the used portion of your partition. In addition to the partimage backup, I would also backup your config files in the /etc/ directory.

Comment: How would you upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04? that's impossible...

Comment: Thanks Jokerdino, I guess that was the assurance needed :)
I have a 2nd 1tb disk just for backups